# For RF in STM32WB, is it necessary to make a ground layer on the PCB lower layer under the PCB antenna (for example for 2450AT18B100)?

Tags: rf, stm32

And by the way, there is no information in any manual for antennas, but is it necessary to make a ground layer on the bottom PSB side under the antenna?
since I didn’t make, under the antenna on the bottom and  top layer a ground layer (I have two layers of the board)
[image]

Comment: No ground plane under antenna. You should not put ground plane under antenna.

Comment: I meant under the antenna on the bottom side of PCB board, 
don't need, is it correct?

Comment: I also meant it.